# Print Spooler has stopped in PrintManager

Tags: android, print-spooler-api

I am using PrintManager(when webview is loaded) as follow:

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName));
printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
```

When save button is clicked, HTML is saved as pdf. 
When this process is done very fast i.e. while preview is loading, getting the following exception
"Unfortunately Print Spooler has stopped"

```
process: com.android.printspooler, PID: 5705
                                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: end cannot be less than zero.
                                                     at android.print.PageRange.<init>(PageRange.java:50)
                                                     at com.android.printspooler.util.PageRangeUtils.asAbsoluteRange(PageRangeUtils.java:199)
                                                     at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity$DocumentTransformer.computePagesToShred(PrintActivity.java:2620)
                                                     at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity$DocumentTransformer.<init>(PrintActivity.java:2496)
                                                     at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity.transformDocumentAndFinish(PrintActivity.java:1733)
                                                     at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity.-wrap15(PrintActivity.java)
                                                     at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity$4.run(PrintActivity.java:620)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Any suggestion to solve or catch this exception

Comment: anyone has idea about this job how to resolve this issue Ajit